# Need help in evaluating this definite integral

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I have been trying to solve this integral. Have not had any success. Any help would be appreciated.

I know the answer is $2\pi^2$, I need the solution

$$ \int\limits_0^\infty\frac{\ln^2\left(x\right)}{\left(1-x\right)^2\sqrt{x}}dx $$

Comment: What have you tried?